# Angular2 Passing parameters to web service http GET

Tags: node.js, rest, http, angular

I have a profileComponent which is making a GET call to service endpoint as follows ,  AparmentService is injected in bootstarp, hence no providers

```
@Component({
    selector: 'profile',
    template: `<h1>Profile Page</h1>

 {{userEmail.email}}
 {{profileObject | json}}
 `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]    
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    userEmail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    public profileObject: Object[];


    constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService) { 
        this.apartmentService = apartmentService;
    }

    ngOnInit(): any {
        console.log(this.userEmail.email);                <--This value displays fine in the console 
        this.apartmentService.getProfile(this.userEmail.email).subscribe(res => this.profileObject = res);  <-- getting [] response for this 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.profileObject));   <-- undefined         
    }
}
```

The service looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class ApartmentService {

    http: Http;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    getProfile(userEmail :string){
       return this.http.get('/api/apartments/getprofile/:userEmail').map((res: Response) => res.json());
    } 
}
```

when I try to hit the endpoint directly in the browser with the parameter, I am getting the respone. But not within Angular.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.get()` is async

```
ngOnInit(): any {
    console.log(this.userEmail.email);                <--This value displays fine in the console 
    this.apartmentService.getProfile(this.userEmail.email).subscribe(res => this.profileObject = res);  <-- getting [] response for this 
    // at this position the call to the server hasn't been made yet.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.profileObject));   <-- undefined         
}
```

When the response from the server arives `res => this.profileObject = res` is executed. `console.log()` is made before the call to the server was even initalized

Use instead

```
ngOnInit(): any {
    console.log(this.userEmail.email);                <--This value displays fine in the console 
    this.apartmentService.getProfile(this.userEmail.email)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.profileObject = res; 
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.profileObject));
    });
}
```

I think `:userEmail` in the URL isn't doing what you expect. Try instead:

```
getProfile(userEmail :string){
   return this.http.get(`/api/apartments/getprofile/${userEmail}`).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: just adding those curly braces ? I tried, no change.

Comment: Sorry, somehow moving up the `console.log(...)` line got lost.

Comment: Still the same behavior. I think I'm doing something wrong in passing the parameters.

Comment: Still same behavior. works on directly accessing the endpoint, not through angular. trying to display the response in the template **{{profileObject | json}}**

Comment: I would need more debugging info. Hard to tell what's actually happening without running code. Move out the string interpolation from the `get(...)` call and print the result to be sure the result is as expected. I don't use TS/JS myself and don't know details about string interpolation.

Comment: console.log inside the getProfile() of service, does print the value. so the value is getting passed. So the http.get syntax might be the issue.

Comment: I have no doubt the value is passed. My doubt was about string interpolation. It seems you want `:userEmail` in `'/api/apartments/getprofile/:userEmail'` being replaced by the value of `userEmail:string`.

Comment: My bad. i didn't notice the back tick in the http get which you changed. It is working with that changes that you suggested. Thanks A lot.